# How do I configure logback to use xz compression for my logs automatically?

Tags: logging, logback, xz

How do I configure logback to use xz compression for my logs automatically?
Is xz even supported or only gz and zip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, logback doesn't support `xz`. You can see it in [source for `RollingPolicyBase.java`](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/RollingPolicyBase.java#L47) and [source for `Comressor.java`](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/helper/Compressor.java)